# Select tag with SelectList don't show in browser when append by javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, select, viewbag, selectlist

I want to show Select List in table in MVC. But It just return nothing in browser like this:
select asp-items= "Microsoft.AspNetCore.mvc.Rendering.SelectList".
Please show me problem.
Here is My code:
In controller:

```
public IActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.objects = new SelectList(app.VatTuRepository.GetObjects(), "Id", "DisplayName");

        return View();
    }
```

In View:

```
 var ele = document.createElement('select');
                ele.setAttribute('asp-items', '@ViewBag.objects');                   

                td.appendChild(ele);
```

and in the browser just show:

```
<select asp-items= "Microsoft.AspNetCore.mvc.Rendering.SelectList"></select>
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: What is expected output? You set an attribute of an HTML select tag, that is not going to populate it

Comment: I want to send list object to database like this :https://www.encodedna.com/javascript/dynamically-add-remove-rows-to-html-table-using-javascript-and-save-data.htm, for each row I have choose object item from select list. I use tag helper but it not populate.